# How to use Microphone port as Headphones

Tags: linux, audio, pulseaudio

How can I convert the microphone jack to output audio (e.g., to headphones) in Kali Linux (or Debian Linux). I want to listen to audio on headphones, but my headphones jack has been broken.

I know it is possible to convert the microphone jack to a headphone jack, because Windows 10 does it automatically.
But I don't know how to do it in Kali Linux (which is basically Debian).

Comment: What exact audio hardware do you have? (The sound card, or the sound chip on the motherboard, not the headphones.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [this](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2013/12/turn-headphone-jack-microphone-jack-ubuntu) article on OMG Ubuntu.

The article is a bit dated, but provides you the necessary background information.

The proper way to install the tools now (at least on Ubuntu) is in https://askubuntu.com/a/456662/425630. You should be able to find the corresponding package for Debian as well.

Please be aware that your hardware has to be recent enough to support re-assigning the audio ports.